# Can you help me to solve recurrence relation T(1)=5, and for all n>=2, T(n)=2T(n-1)+(3*n+1)

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

`T(1)=5`,

and for all `n>=2: T(n)=2T(n-1)+(3*n+1).`

I tried to solve this problem, but I have a problem with 3*n+1. When I put n-1, n-2,..., I don't know how to determine the formula for this problem.

Comment: I might be wrong but looks like `((2^n)*n)`

Comment: When I put n-2, I will not get 3*n-5

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a mathematics question not a computer programming question.

Comment: Such problems can be solved by computer algebra systems, for example https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%3D2T%28n-1%29%2B%283*n%2B1%29 will give you the answer. Given the answer it is easy to verify that it is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is only `(3*n+1)` as term and not `T(3*n+1)` this is solvable. First impression: you have `2T(n-1)` as subterm, so the solution is something like `2^n`.

Through a simple Excel data analysis I found the solution `T(n)=-7-3n+15 * 2^(n-1)`, I will try to solve it per hand and will update my answer if I found the right path.

Edit: This was more difficult than expected...

[image]

Explanation:

- first step is to get a sum formula for `n`. You can derive this pattern from the first few `T(n)`.
- Once you get the pattern, try to get rid of the sum.
- To solve sums, try to get them in a similar format as `sum_(i=1)^n (1) = n` or `sum_(i=0)^n (2^i) = 2^(n+1)-1`
- to do this you can manipulate the index such as `sum_(i=2)^n (n-i) = sum_(i=0)^(n-2) (i)` or to include/exclude elements from the sum.
- the trickiest part was to solve `sum_(i=0)^n ((n-i)*(2^i))`. The idea here is to convert the multiplication (depending on `i`) to a sum (also depending on `i`).
- please note the changing indice-numbers. `sum_(i=0)^n (2^i)` is not the same as `sum_(i=1)^n (2^i)`
- The path is not the most efficient one, simplify as you wish.